# Add a copy of active excel document to Access table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I use VBA to copy data from Excel to Access with this code.

```
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

rst.Open Source:="Tryckflodeskurva", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
    Options:=adCmdTable

For x = 2 To nextrow
  rst.AddNew
  For i = 1 To 12
    rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
  Next i
  rst.Update
Next x

rst.Close
cnn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Now I also want to send the active Excel document and save as attachment in the same Access table. Can anyone please help med with this new code.
Thank you very much